# How does non-namespace specific sysctl variables work in the context of network namespaces?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, sysctl, network-namespace

Let's assume the systctl variables `net.ipv4.tcp_wmem` and `net.ipv4.tcp_rmem`.

To my understanding, these variables can not be set per-namespace ([but very soon apparently](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/356d1833b638bd465672aefeb71def3ab93fc17d)). My understanding is that these variables apply to the init net  namespace **only**, and that any created net namespaces inherit these variables from the init net namespace.

Doing `nsenter --net=/run/docker/netns/[name] sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_wmem` gives `sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem: No such file or directory`.

If new net namespaces inherit these values from the init net namespace, how can I validate this? Trying to validate using the nsenter command does not work too well.

How does non-namespace sysctl variables work for new net namespaces, and how can I validate/check which values applies to any given namespace?

Comment: The commit you're referencing replaces a global variable with a struct field. It was a global value, which is the same value for all namespaces.